# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'projects_id' in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to submit some data to database. However when inserting the $airattributes im getting an error that projects_id (WHICH DOESNT EXIST ANYWHERE, NEITHER IN DB NOR ANY FILE)

**MY CONTROLLER:**

```
        public function newProject(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $attributes = [];
        $attributes['title'] = $data['title'];
        $attributes['start_date'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($data['start_date']));
        $attributes['end_date'] = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($data['end_date']));
        $attributes['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;
        $attributes['description'] = $data['description'];
        $attributes['air'] = '10';
        $attributes['water'] = '19';
        $attributes['lat'] = $data['lat'];
        $attributes['lng'] = $data['lng'];
        $airattributes['dust'] = $data['dust'];
        $airattributes['noise'] = $data['noise'];
        $airattributes['temperature'] = $data['temperature'];
        $airattributes['radiation'] = $data['radiation'];



  //        var_dump($attributes);
  //        return;

        $project = Projects::create($attributes);
        $air = $project->air()->create($airattributes);

        var_dump($data);
        return;
```

**MY projects model**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projects extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'projects';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'created_by', 'description', 'air', 'water', 'lat', 'lng'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function air()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Air');
    }

    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function water()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Water');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\User', 'id', 'created_by');
    }

    public function enrolls()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Enroll', 'project_id', 'id');
    }


    public function lastEdited()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\User', 'id', 'last_edited_by');
    }

}
```

**My Air Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Air extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'projects_air';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'project_id', 'temperature', 'radiation', 'dust', 'noise'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'id',
    ];
}
```

you can test it here for more info: http://188.166.166.143/projects/add

Comment: project_id is in your Air Model file: in $fillable = ['project_id',....]

Comment: yes thats ok. But im getting a message that projects_id has not been found.

projectS <---- with an s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the projects model if you don't specify the foreign key, then I believe in the Air model you should change to 'projects_id' in accordance to the name of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Projects hasMany relationships with Air:

```
public function air()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Air');
    }
```

This, by default assumes that air model have foreign key `projects_id`, **hence the error.**

Since, you have `project_id` foreign key,

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Air', 'project_id');
```

will do.

**Simply**: Changing model name `Projects` to `Project` will solve the problem. Also model names are always singular.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in two way. One you can change you model name to `Project` or you can specify you foreign key in your `air` function. So you can Change you air function to below.

```
public function air()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Air', 'project_id');
}
```

Choose whichever you want. But in Laravel Model name is always singular so I will recommend you to follow the first rule in that way you don't need to specify the foreign key Laravel is smart enough to recognize that automatically.